# numpy matrix algebra error

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following class in Python:

```
import numpy
class KalmanFilterLinear:
    def __init__(self,_A, _B, _H, _x, _P, _Q, _R):
        self.A = _A                      # State transition matrix.
        self.B = _B                      # Control matrix.
        self.H = _H                      # Observation matrix.
        self.current_state_estimate = _x # Initial state estimate.
        self.current_prob_estimate = _P  # Initial covariance estimate.
        self.Q = _Q                      # Estimated error in process.
        self.R = _R                      # Estimated error in measurements.


    def GetCurrentState(self):
        return self.current_state_estimate

    def Step(self,control_vector,measurement_vector):
        #---------------------------Prediction step-----------------------------
        print self.A
        print self.current_state_estimate
        print self.B
        print control_vector
        predicted_state_estimate = self.A * self.current_state_estimate + self.B * control_vector
        predicted_prob_estimate = (self.A * self.current_prob_estimate) * numpy.transpose(self.A) + self.Q
        #--------------------------Observation step-----------------------------
        innovation = measurement_vector - self.H*predicted_state_estimate
        innovation_covariance = self.H*predicted_prob_estimate*numpy.transpose(self.H) + self.R
        #-----------------------------Update step-------------------------------
        kalman_gain = predicted_prob_estimate * numpy.transpose(self.H) * numpy.linalg.inv(innovation_covariance)
        self.current_state_estimate = predicted_state_estimate + kalman_gain * innovation
        # We need the size of the matrix so we can make an identity matrix.
        size = self.current_prob_estimate.shape[0]
        # eye(n) = nxn identity matrix.
        self.current_prob_estimate = (numpy.eye(size)-kalman_gain*self.H)*predicted_prob_estimate
```

I initialize it like this:

```
import numpy as np
state_transition = np.matrix([[1,-1.0/400],[0,1]])
control_matrix = np.matrix([ [1.0/400, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0] ])

observation_matrix = np.eye(2)
observation_matrix[1][1] = 0.0

initial_probability = np.eye(2)

process_covariance = np.zeros(2)
measurement_covariance = np.eye(2)*0.2
initial_state = np.matrix([[INS_h],[0.0]])

kf = KalmanFilterLinear(state_transition, control_matrix, observation_matrix, initial_state, initial_probability, process_covariance, measurement_covariance)
```

Then I run this code to check everything works:

```
kf.Step(initial_state, initial_state )
```

And I get this error:

```
predicted_state_estimate = self.A * self.current_state_es...
Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I don't have much experience with numpy and I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Has `INS_h` a numerical value?

Comment: After fixing indentation in the `KalmanFilterLinear` code, and adding `INS_h = 0.0`, the code runs with no error.